# Does Vitest have an equivalent option to jest's 'transformIgnorePattern'? or how can I prevent moving breakpoint in Vitest?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, vite, vitest

I encountered the same [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138560) as this link suggests.

There is a response that this is due to the sourcemap existing in the virtual and real files, which can be prevented by setting `transformIgnorePattern` option in Jest.

My team has recently migrated to Vite bundler and is looking for the same option.

The problem is that we are facing the same issue as the link suggests, which is moving breakpoint.

How can I prevent this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a `sourceMaps:true` in vscode debugger option.

Placed the following config at `.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Current Test File",
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs",
      "args": ["TZ=UTC", "run", "--config" ,"./vite/vite.config.ts", "${relativeFile}"],
      "smartStep": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "sourceMaps": true // Adding this line works!
    }
  ]
}
```

And now breakpoints are not moving away.